# How do I send a Purge Request

Tags: akamai

I'm trying to purge several URLs via php of Akamai servers. So far I've been using the CCU Rest Api which simply sends a HTTP-Request with the urls and options encoded in json. I've heard that the support of this API will end soon so I wanted to use a different API to do it.

[*I wanted to use this one*](https://developer.akamai.com/api/purge/ccu/overview.html)

Since the documentation is really unstructered and does not tell anything how to send the credentials to the server. I already found their GitHub repositry but I didn't understand anything because I'm pretty new to PHP.

Can someone please explain me how to send only the Purge Request? Validation and checking the results is a piece of cake, the Request is the point where I'm struggeling.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the newer OPEN API, I've written a blog post telling you how to get started

https://community.akamai.com/community/developer/blog/2015/08/20/getting-started-with-the-v2-open-ccu-api

The older API is much less secure, and the newer method will allow, very soon, for 5 second purges.

Let me know if you have any more questions,

Thanks,
Kirsten